# JavaScript canvas drawImage not working properly

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to draw part of an image and it is not work properly.
When i try to use it, the width and height not the same as the original.

Here is my code

```js
window.onload = function() {
ImageObjSketch = new Image(); // URL
ImageObjSketch.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/75lATF9.png';

canvasClone = document.getElementById("squareTarget");
ctxClone = canvasClone.getContext("2d");
ctxClone.drawImage(ImageObjSketch,34,119,16,16,0,0,38,38);
}
```

```css
#squareTarget {
 width: 38px; height: 38px;
 position: relative;
 right: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px #000000 solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="squareTarget"></canvas>
```

As you can see it's not proportional to square, although I set the full size of square.

Another question, as you can see you must run this code twice to see the image, why is that?

Comment: You didn't include your code.

Comment: Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. — Its screams this at you before posting...

Comment: @Veluria & Pogrindis I fixed it just now.

Comment: @Pogrindis I check it and it's not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the canvas explicitly. 
Then you can get 2d Context:

```
window.onload = function() {
var ImageObjSketch = new Image(); // URL
ImageObjSketch.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/75lATF9.png';

var canvasClone = document.getElementById("squareTarget");
  canvasClone.width = 38;
  canvasClone.height = 38;
  ctxClone = canvasClone.getContext("2d");


ctxClone.drawImage(ImageObjSketch, 34,119,16,16,0,0,38,38);
}
```

And then your sizing is 38, but you should use the document height and width, but that's a refactor.

Something like :

```
ctxClone.drawImage(ImageObjSketch, 34,119,16,16,0,0,canvasClone.width,canvasClone.height);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoYbzm

Comment: so I assume that the issue happened to me because the canvas doesn't has width and height attribute?
Another question, why the code require second refresh? I mean that it doesn't  shows the image in first run until you refresh the page.

Comment: Not sure, maybe look into using different event `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
}, false);`